# como vincular las reglas y textos de validacion de un campo de acces con un textbox en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave

End Sub
```

Cuando se vincula un textbox a un campo de una tabla en un formulario access, dicho textbox toma las reglas de validacion del campo antes dicho, exactamente lo mismo quiero hacer pero con un textbox en vb.net. Basicamente quiero que cuando el textbox pierda el foco, esas reglas de validacion se ejecuten y asi mismo muestre un mensaje si no se cumplen.
Entiendo y se que lo puedo hacer yo mismo con codigo pero tengo una base de datos de casi 50 tablas con mas de 30 campos cada una y quiero una solucion mas rapida para poder vincular el textbox con dichas validaciones. Muchas gracias

Comment: Segun tengo entendido, no se puede. Esas son reglas internas del motor de la base, y no son recuperables desde afuera. Pero esperemos a ver si alguien me contradice

Comment: he leido por internet que se podia eliminar las reglas de validacion de access desde vb.net usando una libreria obsoleta DAO 3.6 , Asi que creo que se podria manipular dichas reglas de una maneras mas optimizada